# Select several fields from 3 tables in MySQL but the field must not require exists which in third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables named student, student_lessons and student_image. I want to select student, student lessons and display students image IF EXISTS. Is there anyway to handle it in one query ?

try to select student id, student name, student lesson (must exists) and student image path, student image pic_id if exists

```
# TABLE `students`
id | name | surname
1  : John : Malkovich
2  : John : Smith

# TABLE `students_lessons` ( no AI id here)
student_id | lesson | note
1          : math   : A
1          : geo    : B
2          : math   : C

# TABLE `students_image`
pic_id | student_id | image_path 
1      :  1         : some path       
2      :  1         : some path
3      :  2         : some path
```

if I try to do query with joint, it return zero if it doesn't find any picture. How can I do query to select image if exists in single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT students.* 
FROM students
JOIN students_lessons ON (students_lessons.student_id = students.id)
LEFT JOIN students_image ON (students_image.student_id = students.id)
```

Or if you only care if image exists:

```
SELECT students.* 
FROM students
JOIN students_lessons ON (students_lessons.student_id = students.id)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT si.* 
   FROM students_image si
   WHERE si.student_id = students.id
)
```

I think what you're looking for is a `LEFT JOIN`. Just modify the `SELECT` to your linking. This query selects all students and have lessons, wether they have an image or not.